# How to use manual partitioning during installation?

Tags: partitioning, system-installation

I'd like to see the full How-To on how to use manual partitioning during Ubuntu installation. The existing guides (at least those I found here) cover only automatic part and leave untouched the manual part (or extremely short and contain no pictures).

I'd like to cover such situations:

- [If you have blank disk](https://askubuntu.com/a/343352/171636)
- [If your disk contains Windows installed](https://askubuntu.com/a/343370/171636)
- If your disk contains other systems:
- [If it is GPT, RAID or LVM](https://askubuntu.com/a/465642/171636)
- [If you have a OEM-preinstalled copy of Windows 8](https://askubuntu.com/a/521195/171636)

Comment: For the 'normal' way of installting you can try this question: http://askubuntu.com/questions/6328/how-do-i-install-ubuntu

Comment: Although many people go this route (and it works fine), I prefer to just boot up a standalone gparted distro and do all my partitioning first. I especially like that it "does" everything and shows you how it will turn out *before* it actually writes anything to the disk. That way, it's easy to say "oops" and just start over if you make a mistake or change your mind about any of the details.

Comment: This description may not be working on 16.04 when: - installation is in EFI mode; - there is a previous Windows installation; - you want to create a custom partitioning. When trying to partition the disk so that some of the original partitions remain untouched, the installer hangs before executing the commands, while warning about forced efi installation. (see this bug https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/ubiquity/+bug/1433310). When this happens, the partition table on the disk is not yet touched, but the installation is completely halted with no other option than to restart the computer

Comment: For installing Ubuntu in dual boot mode I used [this](https://itsfoss.com/install-ubuntu-dual-boot-mode-windows/) link. My computer already had windows 7 and Windows 10 and I was trying to install Ubuntu in an unallocated 100 GB space. The instructions worked very smooth for me. Specially the screen-shots while doing the partitioning was really crucial.

Comment: Hi, this is indeed a great thread for ubuntu installing guide. However, I can't seem to understand what to do while installing in EFI mode.

Answer (score 292, accepted):

## If you have blank disk

1. Boot into Ubuntu Installation media. This can be either CD or USB stick.
2. Start the installation. Proceed to Step 4 and choose "Something else":
   [image: Step 4 — Something else]
3. You will see your disk as `/dev/sda` or `/dev/mapper/pdc_*` (RAID case, * means that your letters *are* different from ours)

   Click "New Partition Table..." You will see that you have free space on your disk now:
   [image: free space]
4. (Recommended) Create partition for swap. Swap is the partition for keeping unneeded memory pages, like Windows swap. Also it can be used for hibernation.

   - Select free space and click <kbd>+</kbd>
   - Set parameters like on the picture below:
     [image: Swap parameters]

   Notice that you should set swap size more than you have physical memory in order to use hibernation. Also, you can place it in the end of disk, but thus it will be slow.
5. Create partition for `/` (root fs). This is the filesystem that contains your kernel, boot files, system files, command-line utilities, libraries, system-wide configuration files and logs.

   - Select free space and click <kbd>+</kbd>
   - Set parameters like on the picture below:
     [image: Root fs parameters]

   10 – 20 GiB should be enough
6. Create partition for `/home`. This is the filesystem for your user's files: documents, images, music and videos. It's much more like Users folder in Windows.

   You can do this just like in step 5 and even choose other fs type (though I recommend use ext4 instead of reiserfs. Simply, the first is much more flexible and the second is quicker)
7. (Optional) Create separate partitions for `/boot`, `/tmp` and `/var`. Set their size according to your needs:

   - `/boot` should be 100 – 500 MiB
   - `/var` and `/tmp` should be > 5 GiB
8. If you doubt about which device for boot loader installation to choose, leave it default. It would be set by installer. But sometimes it does mistakes. Let me guide you how to deal with it:

   - If you use only one hard disk, select or leave `/dev/sda` intact.
   - If you use more than one hard disk with no RAID, select the one from which your system does boot. You can also select other disk and set BIOS to boot from it.
   - If you have RAID from which your system starts, it will be `/dev/mapper/...`

   **Be sure that you select entire disk, not a single partition!**

After all, you should see your disk like this:
[image: Final disk layout]

As LiveWireBT noticed in comments, it is recommended to place root partition onto primary partition on MBR scheme disks. However, it belongs to personal taste. Sometimes it's even better to put `/boot` directory on primary and leave root on logical partition.

That's all! You can now click <kbd>Install Now</kbd> and proceed to the installation.

Comment: I used this guide to help me install Peppermint OS but the installer won't let me install /home to a FAT32 or NTFS partition. I am installing alongside windows and I was hoping to share that volume.

Comment: @zkent if you want to use NTFS or FAT32 as your `/home`, you should make small Ext2/3/4 partition and create some symlinks on it pointing to the corresponding directories on the partition you want to share. You can't just place such important parts of the system like `/home` on filesystems that are not designed for them.

Comment: I just noticed that root is a logical partition, shouldn't these instructions recommend that root is on a primary partition on MBR scheme disks?

Comment: I tried this and when I clicked install now it gave me a message box that said "???" "??". Then it went back to where it asks whether you want to erase disk and install Ubuntu or something else...

Comment: @LiveWireBT added your notice into body.

Comment: Why do you say that the `swap` partition is optional?

Comment: @becko because it _is_ optional. However I can change instruction to "recommended".

Comment: Regarding point 7. Is it mandatory for UEFI based machines to have `EFI boot partition` created (200MB)?

Comment: hello, can you please explain and give some instructions for the rest options like `/usr`, `/srv`, `/opt`, `/usr/local`? do i need to give them separated partition? thanks

Comment: Presumably 'swap at the end of the disk is slow' applies only to HDD, not SSD?

Comment: @JonathanHartley Yes, for SSD the order of placement [doesn't matter](http://askubuntu.com/a/261204/35512)

Comment: @Danatela the for articles. Q: Shouldnt the root partition be a primary partition? Plus confirm. Chris.

Comment: Just want to reiterate and confirm @VPR's comment regarding the EFI partition; it was needed in my install and didn't work without it.

Comment: Is there a similar tutorial using gparted somewhere? This tutorial also seems kind of out-of-date.

Comment: @danatela It won't let me creat a partition called swap area.  It requires `/` so I called it `/swaps`.  Hope it works

Comment: @mLstudent33 you have to expand the drop down menu where it says 'ext4 journaling file system' then select 'swap area'.

Comment: I don't recommend to make swap partition at the beginning of disk, only root should be because once root is created, it cannot be moved, however, swap is optional and can be removed and used if root needs more space.

Comment: Most OSs wil create the /efi partition for you automatically if you choose to let them handle the prtition for you, but yes you have to create the /efi manually if you choose manual partition, without the /efi it won't boot @VRR

Comment: Ubuntu uses a swapfile now instead of a swap partition. You could use "Erase disk and install Ubuntu" until the installer shows you what default partitioning it WOULD create and then cancel to DIY instead.

Answer (score 81):

## If you have disk that contains Windows installed

1. Boot from Ubuntu Installation media.
2. Unmount any mounted drives if they exist.
3. Proceed to Step 4. Choose "Something else" and click <kbd>Continue</kbd>:

[image: Something else]

You will see partition table. It will look like this:

[image: partition table]

4. Free some space for Ubuntu:

   - Select the Windows drive (not the loader!). It should be the biggest drive in the map.
   - Click <kbd>Change...</kbd> button. Reduce Windows' partition to 60% of it's size. Notice that you should remain some free space on it (8 – 20 GiB should be enough).
     [image: windows partition resize]
   - If you want, you can delete some partitions. This is done by clicking <kbd>-</kbd> button. **Do not delete Windows partition!**

   And ~40 GiB should be kept for Ubuntu. Click <kbd>OK</kbd> and <kbd>Continue</kbd> to write changes on disk.
5. Now your partition table should look like this:

[image: New partition table]

6. Now, you can proceed with steps 4 – 7 of [part about blank installation](https://askubuntu.com/a/343352/171636). Notice that swap will be placed on logical partition. This doesn't matter, in any case it will work perfect.

Comment: I have experienced difficulties after shrinking a Windows partition using tools on the Linux side.  It may be safer to shrink the Windows partition using Windows tools before beginning the install.  Ref: http://askubuntu.com/questions/511459/dual-boot-ubuntu-12-04-xp-resized-partitions-xp-starts-to-load-but-fails-to

Comment: If you have Logical Disk Manager (LDM) Partition, the partition size shows as "unknown" and you can't resize it. The solution is to do it from inside Windows itself first: https://askubuntu.com/a/976430/52975

Comment: For installing Ubuntu in dual boot mode I used [this](https://itsfoss.com/install-ubuntu-dual-boot-mode-windows/) link. My computer already had windows 7 and Windows 10 and I was trying to install Ubuntu in an unallocated 100 GB space. The instructions worked very smooth for me. Specially the screen-shots while doing the partitioning was really crucial.

Comment: @Danatela if i want to remove windows completely from my computer, should i delete windows partition???

Comment: @FatemehKarimi yep, it's recommended but not mandatory. Often people have significant amount of data on their windows partition, moving it on linux filesystems has pros and cons.

Comment: I have Windows boot manager installed on /dev/sdb (the efi loader is here) whereas I am trying to install ubuntu on /dev/sda. Which drive should I choose for the boot loader installation?

Comment: I'm trying to do above steps on ubuntu server 20.04LTS and not successful. everytime i try i end up losing my windows installation. I found partitioning is very complicated on ubuntu server installation especially if you have windows installed on the same drive and you want to save it or dual boot it.

Answer (score 52):

## If you have a OEM-preinstalled copy of Windows 8 or later

Computers with OEM installs of Windows usually come with more than 1 or 2 partitions. Starting with Windows 8 the partition table should be [GPT](https://askubuntu.com/q/509006/40581), allowing for more than 4 *primary* partitions.

### 1. Resizing the Windows partition

There are at least 2 ways doing this:

- from the live media
- in Windows

#### A. Resizing from Ubuntu live media

You can run GParted or use only the manual partitioning menu of the installer.

#### B. The safer option: Resizing from within Windows

- Resize the Windows partition with *Disk Management* (run `diskmgmt.msc`).

  [image: starting <code>diskmgmt.msc</code> from Windows search]

  Select your Windows partition and choose *"Shrink Volume…"* from the context menu.

  [image]

  This will usually shrink to the minimum possible, you may want to adjust the value to leave more space for Windows.

  [image]
- Optionally ***disable* fast startup** and probably disable hibernation, if it is activated and you intend to access the Windows partition with Ubuntu. Run `powercfg.cpl` and navigate to *Power Options* > *System Settings* through *"Choose what the power button does"*.

  [image: starting <code>powercfg.cpl</code> from Windows search]

  [image]

  [image]

### 2. Manually setting up the partition layout for Ubuntu

- Attention! No, you don't want to erase the entire disk and Windows along with it. Choose the *Something else* option if you see this screen. (*Something else* may be the most difficult option to understand, but considering [existing bugs](http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2014/08/ubuntu-installer-bug-wipes-partitions) you know what you will get.)

  [image]

  [image]
- You will get to the manual partitioning menu, where you should at least create a root partition (`/`) and a swap partition.

  [image]

  - Option 1: add only a root partition

    [image]
  - Option 2: add a root and home partition

    [image]
    [image]

  …finally add the swap partition:

  [image]

  Note that there usually is an existing EFI System Partition (short ESP, `efi` in the screenshot), that the installer will automatically detect and mount to install EFI loaders and programs.

  [image]

---

**Related bug reports**

- [GPT partition tables are not properly detected - Ubiquity suggests erasing disk](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/ubiquity/+bug/1366570)

**Related**

- [My answer](https://superuser.com/a/900235/252532) to SU question: *Clean install Windows 8.1 or Windows 8 from OEM key* (now updated with info for Windows 10)
- Adding an encrypted partition with `pam_mount` during login ([1](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Pam_mount), [2](https://askubuntu.com/a/98284/40581))

Comment: +1 Just to expand the answer: it is safer to have a separate home partition concerning data security, especially if you planing to upgrade Ubuntu later.

Comment: @LiveWireBT My Live usb disk booting in efi mode. Do I need to set mount point to `/boot/efi` for efi partition. Ubuntu 15.04 installer is supposed to do that automatically, but it doesn't.

Comment: @KhurshidAlam Yes, do that if it doesn't do it automatically.

Comment: From 17.04 I don't think you need to swap partition any more.

Comment: If you can't shrink the partition very much, try to disable Windows' Page file and System protection features: https://askubuntu.com/a/976430/52975

Answer (score 19):

### If you have `md` RAID

*I will not cover how to create `mdadm` arrays here. There are [a lot of articles](https://www.google.ru/search?q=how%20to%20create%20mdadm%20raid) around the Internet. However, there is one major problem: Ubiquity installer doesn't account for the arrays created in the live session, so you'll probably get unbootable system after installation on such array.*

1. Create the setup like mine:

   ```
    $ sudo fdisk -l

    Disk /dev/sda: 160.0 GB, 160041885696 bytes
    ...

       Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
    /dev/sda1            2048   156299263    78148608   83  Linux
    /dev/sda2       156299264   311556095    77628416    7  HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
    /dev/sda3   *   311556096   312580095      512000   83  Linux

    Disk /dev/sdb: 80.0 GB, 80026361856 bytes
    ...

       Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
    /dev/sdb1            2048   156301311    78149632   83  Linux

    Disk /dev/md0: 160.0 GB, 160048349184 bytes
    ...

    Disk /dev/md0 doesn't contain a valid partition table
   ```

   As you can guess, I created `/dev/md0` `mdadm` array from `/dev/sda1` and `/dev/sdb1`. It's empty now. Let's install something on it.
2. Create partitions on `/dev/md0` as you like:

   [image: Partitions layout]

   **Important:** Install `/boot` onto one of partition *outside* the array because GRUB doesn't support `mdadm`. In my case, it's `/dev/sda3`. If you want more quick booting of your system, it should be placed at the beginning of the disk.
3. Install Ubuntu. Click <kbd>Continue testing</kbd>. Or reboot and see initramfs prompt [image: ;)]
4. Now, you have to `chroot` into installed system and install `mdadm`:

   ```
    sudo mount /dev/md0p6 /mnt
    sudo mount /dev/md0p5 /mnt/home
    sudo mount /dev/sda3 /mnt/boot
    for d in /dev /proc /sys /run; do sudo mount --bind $d /mnt$d; done
    chroot /mnt
    apt-get install mdadm
   ```

   Installing `mdadm` should fix booting problem.

Answer (score 4):

Do any of the following help you? (sorry, I don't have enough rep to comment this).

> Now suppose that we are going to install Ubuntu 11.04 and at first of the installation process we will meet Allocate drive space screen (the most important step in the installation process). In Allocate drive space screen Select Something else to partition your disk drive manually.
>
> The Next screen shows sda1 partition for Windows Xp and free space, Now we are going to install Ubuntu 11.04 so we need to create / partition and Swap.
>
> **Create / Partition**:
>
> Select free space and press on Add button.
>
> Ubuntu 11.04 requires about 4.4 GB, So we should type a value more than 4.4 GB. Here in my case I put 6000 MB i.e 6 GB.
>
> From "Use as" I selected Ext4 journalling file system.
>
> From "Mount point" I selected /.
>
> Press Add button to create / partition.
>
> **Create Swap:**
>
> In the previous screen select free space, and press Add button.
>
> Swap doesn't need much space. In my case I put 500 MB
>
> From "Use as" select Swap area
>
> No need to Mount point.
>
> Click Ok button to create swap.
>
> **Install:**
>
> Now we have /, partition, and swap so we are ready to install.
>
> To start installation process press Install now button.

[Manual partitioning on Ubuntu installation](http://linuxtop.blogspot.co.uk/2011/08/allocate-drive-space-for-ubuntu-1104.html)

For installing Windows on a separate partition, this should be fairly self explanatory from the "Install Ubuntu alongside them" option, however you may come across the following bug.

> Your existing partition (Windows) is on the left, Ubuntu is on the right. That's the standard order when shrinking one partition to create another for dual-booting.

[Installing Ubuntu with Windows installed on a partition](https://askubuntu.com/questions/150550/installing-ubuntu-with-windows-which-is-left-and-right-when-allocating-space)

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Comment: I agree, and I am more than happy to bring in the textual parts of the links, however copying print screens from the attached resources seems somewhat superfluous (and they probably supply the "better" answer).

Answer (score 4):

**Partition shows "unknown" Used in GParted**

This happened to me on 17.10 because my Windows 10 Lenovo P51 used a Logical Disk Manager (LDM) Partition.

The solution was to shrink the partition from inside Windows as shown at: https://askubuntu.com/a/521195/52975

You can then install Ubuntu on the free space allocated.

**Cannot shrink disk fully**

Then I hit the second problem: Windows said I had 400Gb of free space in the partition, but I could only shrink 250Gb.

The solution was to go inside Windows and:

- Disable Page File (AKA Windows' swap)
- Disable System Protection

as mentioned at: https://superuser.com/questions/1017764/how-to-shrink-a-windows-10-partition/1060508#1060508

Then after the reboot, it let me shrink it all the way.